# Thread.CurrentCulture not saving to instance variable?

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

[image]

As you can see, I attempt to capture the Thread's CurrentCulture to an instance variable so that I can reuse it througout the class, however it is not persisting. In the above photo, I show that even after assigning it, the values are still different. Why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not persisting"? Is the *stored* value changed?

Comment: I meant that it was not persisting between the constructor call and the Action call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of possibly reasons why this could happen

- The `PickLanguage` method is executing on a different thread which has a different culture
- The culture of the thread was changed.

Either of these would cause the cached culture to differ from the current culture.  In general caching values named `Current` is dangerous because it's an indication that they can and will change

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to make this thread safe? I'm assuming this is inherent to the controller class. If were to move this out into a separate command class for example, wouldn't that ensure it gets run on the same thread?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic this isn't really an issue of thread safety, it's more of a caching policy problem. My advice would be to simply not cache the value.  Or only cache it locally at the start of the method vs. on the type

Comment: @Sinaesthetic I'm not sure where threading issue come - your code does not show any... As precaution - don't create threads manually in actions and your life should be much better... Consider using async support - the current context will be carried to new threads for you...

Comment: @JaredPar FWIW, i attempted to move the logic into its own command class and tried again and it worked. So it was a threading issue, and seemingly related to the framework's control over multithreading the controller.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - so where your threading concerns come from? Unless you use async the controller will be created and work on single thread for whole request and other unique instances of controller for other requests will run on separate threads with own copy of all `.CurrentXXXX` objects...

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - note that there is plenty of code runs between constructor and action (like action filters) - so check out that code first.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I am not using anything async, however it would seem that something else in the mix is. I have no additional filters or the like added to the request flow. However, it seems to be obvious that the call to new up the controller and the call to the action were on separate threads. When I moved the logic to a separate class, it worked fine since by this point, I knew it was on the same thread as the call to that class.